# How do I detect mouse entered on a SKSpriteNode in OSX development using SpriteKit and Swift?

Tags: macos, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

If I have a SKSpriteNode in a SKScene:

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")

champion.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
champion.setScale(0.25)

self.addChild(champion)
```

Now after I add this node to the scene, I want to change its colour when I move the mouse over this node.

How do I detect mouse hover on this node so that I can change its colour?

I see a mouseEntered event in SKSpriteNode class.
Do I use that? How can it be fired?

Or should I use other approaches?

Answer (score 7):

In `didMoveToView`, define an `NSTrackingArea` to track mouse events and add it to the view

```
    let options = [NSTrackingAreaOptions.MouseMoved, NSTrackingAreaOptions.ActiveInKeyWindow] as NSTrackingAreaOptions
    let trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect:view.frame,options:options,owner:self,userInfo:nil)
    view.addTrackingArea(trackingArea)
```

Declare a sprite and add it to the scene for testing purposes

```
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
    sprite.name = "sprite"
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(view.frame), CGRectGetMidY(view.frame));
    sprite.setScale(0.5)
    self.addChild(sprite)
```

Override the `mouseMoved` method

```
override func mouseMoved(event: NSEvent) {
    // Get mouse position in scene coordinates
    let location = event.locationInNode(self)
    // Get node at mouse position
    let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
    if (node.name == "sprite") {
        let sprite = node as SKSpriteNode
        sprite.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
        sprite.color = SKColor.greenColor()
    }
}
```

Lastly, you'll need to remove the `NSTrackingArea` from the view when you transition to a new scene

```
override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {
    for trackingArea in view.trackingAreas {
        view.removeTrackingArea(trackingArea)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. And is there a way that the hover were detected only when cursor hovers over the spaceship figure instead of the rectangular it's in?

Comment: @0x141E can you help me with a similar Tracking area issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902106/i-have-created-a-custom-cursor-and-a-tracking-area-i-want-to-updatecursor-when

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus sorry, I'm more familiar with developing for iOS than Mac OS X.